# Laravel JSON output formatting

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a subpage that draws the letters for each table. For example, I give 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and a, b, c. Below is the code that processes the result:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
    <div class="card mt-5">
        <div class="card-header" style="z-index: 1000;">
            <h2>Results {{response()->json([$teams_json])->getContent()}}</h2>
        </div>     
    </div>
@endsection
```

The result of the JSON response:

```
Result: [{"a":["2","3"],"b":["1","5"],"c":["4"]}]
```

How can I format my result to look like this?

```
Result:
   - a: 2,3
   - b: 1,5
   - c: 4
```

Comment: You can't just magically convert one format to the other without a little help. Are you referring to pretty print with json encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to loop it and print them the way you wish. Since you're using Blade, you can use [`@foreach`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops).
Try the following:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
    <div class="card mt-5">
        <div class="card-header" style="z-index: 1000;">
            <h2>Results {{response()->json([$teams_json])->getContent()}}</h2>
            @foreach ($teams_json as $team => $no)
                {{ $team }}: {{ implode($no) }}
            @endforeach
        </div>     
    </div>
@endsection
```